# Converting .xml image annotations to masks (.jpg or .png)

Tags: xml, annotations, dataset, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I'm using the LabelMe annotation tool, after annotating the labels are in .xml format. But my neural network takes annotations as .png. How to convert from .xml to .jpg or .png? 
The .xml file has information of bounding boxes of objects.